# shared object can't find symbols in main binary, C++

Tags: c++, dlopen, shared-objects

I'm experimenting with making a kind of plugin architecture for a program I wrote, and at my first attempt I'm having a problem. Is it possible to access symbols from the main executable from within the shared object? I thought the following would be fine:

testlib.cpp:

```
void foo();
void bar() __attribute__((constructor));
void bar(){ foo(); }
```

testexe.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

void foo()
{
    cout << "dynamic library loaded" << endl;    
}

int main()
{
    cout << "attempting to load" << endl;
    void* ret = dlopen("./testlib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(ret == NULL)
        cout << "fail: " << dlerror() << endl;
    else
        cout << "success" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -fPIC -o testexe testexe.cpp -ldl
g++ --shared -fPIC -o testlib.so testlib.cpp
```

Output:

```
attempting to load
fail: ./testlib.so: undefined symbol: _Z3foov
```

So obviously, it's not fine. So I guess I have two questions:
1) Is there a way to make the shared object find symbols in the executable it's loaded from
2) If not, how do programs that use plugins typically work that they manage to get code in arbitrary shared objects to run inside their programs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
g++ -fPIC -rdynamic -o testexe testexe.cpp -ldl
```

Without the `-rdynamic` (or something equivalent, like `-Wl,--export-dynamic`), symbols from the application itself will not be available for dynamic linking.

Comment: According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/Link-Options.html, the same effect can be achieved with the option "-rdynamic" to the gcc link step.

Comment: Why `-fPIC` though? It's creating an executable, not a shared library. I think `-fPIC` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

From *The Linux Programming Interface*:

> ##### 42.1.6 Accessing Symbols in the Main Program
>
> Suppose that we use `dlopen()` to dynamically load a shared library, use `dlsym()` to obtain
> the address of a function `x()` from that library, and then call `x()`. If
> `x()` in turn calls a function `y()`, then `y()` would normally be sought in
> one of the shared libraries loaded by the program. Sometimes, it is
> desirable instead to have `x()` invoke an implementation of `y()` in the
> main program. (This is similar to a callback mechanism.) In order to
> do this, we must make the (global-scope) symbols in the main program
> available to the dynamic linker, by linking the program using the
> `––export–dynamic` linker option:
>
> `$ gcc -Wl,--export-dynamic main.c` (plus further options and arguments)
>
> Equivalently, we can write the
> following:
>
> `$ gcc -export-dynamic main.c`
>
> Using either of these options
> allows a dynamically loaded library to access global symbols in the
> main program.
>
> The `gcc –rdynamic` option and the `gcc –Wl,–E` option are
> further synonyms for `–Wl,––export–dynamic`.